# How to add unique Webi Report Filter for charts

Tags: business-intelligence, business-objects

I have a report which have 5 different charts on the same sheet. I need to apply filters for the charts that I display. Each filter is different for the charts where 2 charts have common filters. The user viewing the report should be able to select the value from the filter for each chart. How can I obtain this by having separate filter for different charts?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use **Input Controls**.  You can specify one or more blocks (charts) that each Input Control will apply to.